# Сортировка строк матрицы по минимальному элементу строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана матрица и нужно её преобразовать таким образом,чтобы строки матрицы были отсортированы в зависимости от минимального элемента каждой строки.
То есть входные данные такие

```
[7,2,5,12]
[10,7,3,22]
[23,45,6,1]
[16,4,9,34]
```

А выходные должны быть такими

```
[23,45,6,1] - мин.эл 1
[7,2,5,12] - мин.эл 2
[10,7,3,22] - мин.эл 3
[16,4,9,34] - мин.эл 4
```

Функцию `Sort()` использовать нельзя
Было сделано следующее

```
   A1=[[1.3, 2.5, 4.5, 0.8], 
    [0.1, 4.2, 3.4, 2.8],
    [3.1, 1.7, 2,2, 4.5],
    [0.3, 0.6, 5,1, 0.7],
    [2.5, 3.5, 0.4, 5.3],
    [1.2, 2.4, 1.8, 7.2]]

print("Сформированная матрица:")
for i in range(len(A1)):                 
    for j in range(len(A1[i])):           
        print(A1[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()

print("Преобразованная матрица")    
min=0;
for i in range(len(A1)):
    for j in range(len(A1[0])):
        if A1[i[j]< A1[0]{j]:
                  min= A1[i][j]
                  A1[i][j]= A1[0][j];
                  A1[0][j]= min
                  print(" Минимальный элемент",  i," строки = ", min)
              
for i in range(len(A1)):                 
    for j in range(len(A1[i])):           
        print(A1[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
```

В коде выше, вывел матрицы с помощью цикла нахожу минимальный элемент,заношу его в специальную переменную `min` но что именно дальше делать?Нашёл минимальный элемент,как сделать сортировку строк не используя `sort()`

Comment: Почитайте про "пузырьковую сортировку", например. Там цикл в цикле, ищете минимум и меняете местами элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, конечно, схитрить, использовав не `sort`, а `sorted`:
`A2 = sorted(A1, key=min)`

Используется "пузырьковая сортировка" - не слишком оптимально, но вполне наглядно:

```
A1=[[1.3, 2.5, 4.5, 0.8], 
    [0.1, 4.2, 3.4, 2.8],
    [3.1, 1.7, 2,2, 4.5],
    [0.3, 0.6, 5,1, 0.7],
    [2.5, 3.5, 0.4, 5.3],
    [1.2, 2.4, 1.8, 7.2]]

def print_matrix(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for el in row:
            print(el, end=' ')
        print()
    print()
    
def sort_matrix(matrix):
    min_elements = [min(row) for row in matrix] # запоминаем минимальные элементы
    matrix_len = len(matrix)
    # собственно, "пузырьковая сортировка"
    for k in range(matrix_len-1):
        for i in range(matrix_len-k-1):
            if min_elements[i] > min_elements[i+1]:
                min_elements[i], min_elements[i+1] = min_elements[i+1], min_elements[i]
                matrix[i], matrix[i+1] = matrix[i+1], matrix[i]
    return None

print_matrix(A1)
sort_matrix(A1)
print_matrix(A1)
```